# Keep Ubuntu installations across multiple systems equal

Tags: ubuntu, sync, file-transfer, file-management

Is there a way to have lets say to computers running Ubuntu, and every time I install something to one system, it somehow syncs up with a server, as to what was installed, and as soon as i start the other system, is installs the same programs/packages? Bonus would obviously be Even file syncs, without relying to much on Dropbox, OneDrive, etc ...

Comment: What happens if both computers are used simultaneously?

Comment: They wont, as far as i am planning